# How do I sort Lucene results by field value using a HitCollector?

Tags: search, lucene

I'm using the following code to execute a query in Lucene.Net

```
var collector = new GroupingHitCollector(searcher.GetIndexReader());
searcher.Search(myQuery, collector);
resultsCount = collector.Hits.Count;
```

How do I sort these search results based on a field?

---

### Update

Thanks for [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497609/sorting-lucene-search-results/500409#500409). I had tried using `TopFieldDocCollector` but I got an error saying, `"value is too small or too large"` when i passed `5000` as `numHits` argument value. Please suggest a valid value to pass.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`search.Searcher.search`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Weight,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Sort%29) method will accept a [`search.Sort`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html) parameter, which can be constructed as simply as:

```
new Sort("my_sort_field")
```

However, there are some limitations on which fields can be sorted on - they need to be indexed but not tokenized, and the values convertible to `String`s, `Float`s or `Integer`s.

[Lucene in Action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher2/) covers all of the details, as well as sorting by multiple fields and so on.

Comment: ...and not tokenized - beat me to it :)

Comment: @janwen According to the docs for Lucene, it is not required that the value be stored, only indexed

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably [TopFieldDocCollector](http://hudson.zones.apache.org/hudson/job/Lucene-trunk/javadoc//org/apache/lucene/search/TopFieldDocCollector.html). Use it instead of the `GroupingHitCollector` (what is that?), or inside it.

Comment on this if you need more info. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: thanks for your answer......... I had tried using TopFieldDocCollector but i got an error saying "value is too small or too large" when i passed 5000 as numHits argument value...please suggest a valid value to pass...

Answer (score 0):

In the original (Java) version of Lucene, there is no hard restriction on the size of the the `TopFieldDocCollector` results. Any number greater than zero is accepted. Although memory constraints and performance degradation create a practical limit that depends on your environment, 5000 hits is trivial and shouldn't pose a problem outside of a mobile device.

Perhaps in porting Lucene, `TopFieldDocCollector` was modified to use something other than Lucene's "heap" implementation (called `PriorityQueue`, extended by `FieldSortedHitQueue`)—something that imposes an unreasonably small limit on the results size. If so, you might want to look at the source code for `TopFieldDocCollector`, and implement your own similar hit collector using a better heap implementation.

I have to ask, however, why are you trying to collect 5000 results? No user in an interactive application is going to want to see that many. I figure that users willing to look at 200 results are rare, but double it to 400 just as factor of safety. Depending on the application, limiting the result size can hamper malicious screen scrapers and mitigate denial-of-service attacks too.

Comment: "No user in an interactive application is going to want to see that many" is a bit presumptuous. Users scream and complain even when we truncate to 200,000 for legitimate technical reasons...

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for Sort accepting only the string field name has been depreciated. Now you have to create a sort object and pass it in as the last paramater of [searcher.Search()](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Sort))

```
/* sorting by a field of type long called "size" from greatest -> smallest 
(signified by passing in true for the last isReversed paramater)*/

Sort sorter = new Sorter(new SortField("size", SortField.Type.LONG, true))
searcher.Search(myQuery, collector, sorter);
```