# Can Neo4j be effectively used to show a collection of nodes in a sortable and filterable table?

Tags: neo4j

I realise this may not be ideal usage, but apart from all the graphy goodness of Neo4j, I'd like to show a collection of nodes, say, People, in a tabular format that has indexed properties for sorting and filtering

I'm guessing the Type of a node can be stored as a Link, say Bob -> type -> Person, which would allow us to retrieve all People

Are the following possible to do efficiently (indexed?) and in a scalable manner?

- Retrieve all People nodes and display all of their names, ages, cities of birth, etc (NOTE: some of this data will be properties, some Links to other nodes (which could be denormalised as properties for table display's and simplicity's sake)
- Show me all People sorted by Age
- Show me all People with Age < 30

Also a quick how to do the above (or a link to some place in the docs describing how) would be lovely

Thanks very much!

Oh and if the above isn't a good idea, please suggest a storage solution which allows both graph-like retrieval and relational-like retrieval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to operate on these person nodes, you can put them into an index (default is Lucene) and then retrieve and sort the nodes using Lucene (see for instance [How do I sort Lucene results by field value using a HitCollector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497609/how-do-i-sort-lucene-results-by-field-value-using-a-hitcollector) on how to do a custom sort in java). This will get you for instance People sorted by Age etc. The code in Neo4j could look like

```
Transaction tx = neo4j.beginTx();
idxManager = neo4j.index()
personIndex = idxManager.forNodes('persons')
personIndex.add(meNode,'name',meNode.getProperty('name'))
personIndex.add(youNode,'name',youNode.getProperty('name'))
tx.success()
tx.finish()


'*** Prepare a custom Lucene query context with Neo4j API ***'
query = new QueryContext( 'name:*' ).sort( new Sort(new SortField(     'name',SortField.STRING, true ) ) )
results = personIndex.query( query )
```

For combining index lookups and graph traversals, [Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-start.html#start-node-by-index-query) is a good choice, e.g.

```
START people = node:people_index(name="E*") MATCH people-[r]->() return people.name, r.age order by r.age asc
```

in order to return data on both the node and the relationships.

Comment: can neo4j make use of an index when sorting by a relationship property (r.age in this case)?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that's easily possible with the Neo4j query language [Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-query-lang.html).

For example:

```
start cat=node:Types(name='Person') 
match cat<-[:IS_A]-person-[born:BORN]->city
where person.age > 30
return person.name, person.age, born.date, city.name
order by person.age asc
limit 10
```

You can experiment with it in our [cypher console](http://console.neo4j.org).

Comment: Thanks, (Peter got in first!)